# Checked Out New Project in XCode 6.1 but XCTest and other libraries are missing

Tags: xcode, github, frameworks, libraries, xctest

Today I checked out a new copy of stable project from gitHub to my home computer using Xcode 6.1. After doing so, I see that many of the frameworks and libraries, including XCTest, are missing (shown in red). I have added Framework and Header Search Paths, but they are still not found.

To make things stranger, I can build the project to a simulator or device, but when I try to run an individual test, I get clang or missing file error for the libraries/frameworks shown in red.

Comment: Did you mean to attach any images?

Comment: No images attached. When I said "shown in red" I mean the left panel in Xcode, whee missing items are often shown in red.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, the reason for my errors was that I had not run "Build for Testing" before trying to run the individual Unit Tests. As such, the proper library dependencies had not been generated.